# jquery no conflicting error

Tags: jquery

I have particular set of files for toggle effect. When I use these two files separtely it works for me. But I use to copy the files with collection of my js files so it start giving me error. Its giving me conflicting error. When firebug. It shows error on first file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//$.noConflict();
    $('.toggle_block').toggleElements({
        fxAnimation:'slide',
        fxSpeed:'fast',
        className:'toggler'
    });

});
 </script>
```

Firebug Error is:

```
$(".toggle_block").toggleElements is not a function
className:'toggler'
```

Its minified version is on jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/cHjMD/

Every time I got conflicting error, I use to remove it using `$.noConflict();` and sometime it sorted out my error also. But this time Its not helping me. I want to permanently sorted out this problem. Here also I have commented noconflict code.

Request please don't provide me link to read noConflict function. I have read it many times. If you define in more better way then I would be pleased.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

In javascript the $ is not a special character - unlike PHP where it indicates the start of a variable, in javacript it is just another character and can be used as part of any variable.  jQuery has decided to use the variable var $ as a shortcut to the jQuery object.  Again, because $ isnt a special reserved word for jQuery, any library or script may also try to use it, which will cause conflicts.

The $.noConflict(); function tells jQuery to give up control of the $ variable and restores it to whatever other library was using it.  After you call it, $ no longer represents jQuery.  This is why you get the error message.

The solution I posted above works because it does not use the $ alias to set up the document.ready function and instead uses the full jQuery object.  Also, the ready() function gets passed the jQuery object as a parameter... so by using $ as the parameter name, the $ variable now represents jQuery once again, but only within the scope of the document.ready function.

The library you linked to in jsfiddle is set up properly to use no-conflict mode, so its possible you have a conflicting library but are never telling jquery to use no-conflict mode.  Try adding the noconflict call above the document ready.. IE

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Comment: Where ever I am getting this error I have to change this... Please explain wat its actually doing..

Comment: Though the error has been removed from my first file whose code I have pasted above. But now Its giving me error on my library whose jsfiddle link I have provided.

Comment: For this method is there a way that you can make a website work both with jQuery or with $ because half the site is done in a manner and the plugins are al in the opposite manner.  ?

Comment: the jQuery object is always available unless you call noconflict with a parameter of true jQuery.noConflict(true); .  the $ is just a shortcut to it.  You should be able to safely wrap all your sites code in this without a problem.